# Use if-loop to calculate price depending on the input in js

Tags: javascript, react-native, if-statement, price

I'm pretty new to Javascript and React, so please bear with me. 
I have a component in my app, that is taking a timespan from the user, but now I want to calculate the price the user would have to pay, depending on their input. I figured that it would probably be the easiest way to use an if loop but something is very off with that and I am a little stuck.

Is my attempt okay in general or does it need a separate function that I have to call in order to do what I want to do?

```js
 onConfirm(hour, minute) {
    this.setState({ time: `Dauer: ${hour}:${minute}` });
    this.setState(if((hour) < 4){return price = `Preis: (${hour}* 1.5) €`;}
      else {return price= 'Preis: 5.50 €';} );
    this.TimePicker.close();
  }
```

Comment: There is no "if loop." `if` statements aren't loops (loops are things like `for`, `while`, etc. -- things that repeat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within an object literal, you can't use statements, only expressions. `if` is a statement.

If you want to do that either/or logic in an expression, you use the *conditional operator* (`? :`), like this:

```
onConfirm(hour, minute) {
    this.setState({
        time: `Dauer: ${hour}:${minute}`,
        price: hour < 4 ? `Preis: (${hour}* 1.5) €` : 'Preis: 5.50 €'
    });
    this.TimePicker.close();
}
```

The conditional operator expression in the above is:

```
hour < 4 ? `Preis: (${hour}* 1.5) €` : 'Preis: 5.50 €'
```

It's a ternary operator (an operator accepting three operands):

1. The condition to test (`hour < 4`)
2. The expression to evaluate if the condition is truthy¹ (`` `Preis: (${hour}* 1.5) €` ``)
3. The expression to evaluate if the condition is falsy¹ (`'Preis: 5.50 €'`)

Also note you had a closing `'` on a template literal (needed a backtick instead).

---

¹ "truthy" and "falsy" - JavaScript implicitly converts (or coerces) values. When you use a value as a test, such as in an `if` or a conditional operator, JavaScript converts the value you provide to a boolean value (`true` or `false`). Values that convert to `true` are called "truthy" values, ones that convert to `false` are called "falsy." The falsy values are `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`, and of course `false` (on browsers, `document.all` is also falsy for various reasons I explain in my book). All other values are truthy.